# "geodMachServiceBridge" errors in Console App

Tags: macos, console

"geodMachServiceBridge" errors show up every few seconds in the Console App in macOS Sierra. Quitting process from within Activity Monitor didn't help.
[image]
Tried this solution (from [here](https://gist.github.com/junkblocker/025014c7db853e6e367258c1ac2e1ad1)), didn't help too:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.geodMachServiceBridge.plist
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.geodMachServiceBridge.plist
```

Shows following error:

> Operation not permitted while System Integrity Protection is engaged

Googling relevant names "com.apple.GeoServices" and "GEODiskSpaceManager" didn't return any valuable results as well.

Before trying to disable SIP, decided to ask the community if anyone have any useful info. Thanks.